# Is the set $ \{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :\ y=0 \} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0 \ \text{and}\ xy=1\} $ connected?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let

> $$ X=\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :\ y=0 \} \cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0 \ \text{and}\ xy=1\}. $$ Then whether this set is connected or not?

I feel the set is connected. Since as $x$ goes to infinity then the $\text{graph}(f)$ about to touche the $x-$axis but unable to give a concrete argument.

Comment: It might be worth noting that $\{(x,y):y=0\}$ and $\{(x,y):x>0,xy=1\}$ are disjoint closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: $\wedge$ and $\vee$ stand in for “and” and “or” respectively in logic statements

Answer (score 2):

If you have a subspace $X$ of $Y$, and $A, B$ are non-empty subsets of $X$, then $A$ and $B$ form a separation of $X$ if $A\cap B = \phi$, $A\cup B = X$, and neither of them contains a limit point of the other.
Use this to infer that $\{ (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :\ y=0 \}$ and $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x>0 \ \text{and}\ xy=1\}$ form a separation of $X$. Hence, $X$ is not connected.

Answer (score 1):

The set $X$ is not connected because you can separate it with two non-empty disjoint open sets. To find two such sets draw how $X$ looks like. Can you think of any curve strictly between $y=0$ and $y=1/x$? What about $y=1/(2x)$?

With this in mind you just need to take $X_1=\{(x,y):x>0,y>1/(2x)\}$ and $X_2=\mathbb{R}\setminus\overline{X_1}$, and check that this two sets satisfy the conditions above.